# Global variable laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

can i create a global variable of the input form to be called in the controller?

form

```
<form method="post" action="/dashboard">
  @csrf
  <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="outlet" class="form-label">Outlet</label>
           <select class="form-select" name="outlet_id" id="outlet_id">
            @foreach ($outlets-> as $outlet)
                  <option value="{{ $outlet->id }}">{{ $outlet->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
           </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-12">Submit</button>
</form>
```

controller

```
   public function index(Request $request){
        $data = $request->outlet_id;
        Session::put('outlet', $data);
        Session::get('outlet');
        $role = Session::get('role');
        $collection = array("blue", "purple", "green", "red");
        
        if($role->role == "admin" || $role->role == "owner"){
            return view('dashboard.index', [
                'tittle' => 'Dashboard',
                'stocks' => StockGudang::all(),
                'products' => Product::all(),
                'collection' => $collection
            ]);
        }else{
            $outlet = Session::get('outlet');
            return view('dashboard.index', [
                'tittle' => 'Dashboard',
                'stocks' => StockGudang::all()->where('outlet_id', $outlet),
                'products' => Product::all(),
                'collection' => $collection
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I have tried using `Session::put`, but when I refresh the value will disappear

Comment: You seem to be passing multiple variables to your view. Why is this not good enough?

Comment: Does this help, using request instance? [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/session#storing-data)

Answer (score -1):

Try using [VIEW COMPOSERS](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#view-composers). The variable `$outlet` will be available in any blade view.

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('*', function($view) {
            $view->with(['outlet' => request()->get('outlet_id', null)]);
            // if you need to access in controller and views:
            Config::set('something', $something); 
        });
    }
```

Comment: where do I put this? is it on the controller?

Comment: and how do i call `$outlet` in the controller?

Comment: If you set it via `Config`, you just get `Config::get('outlet')`, If it's inside a blade, just call a `$outlet ` variable

Comment: A bit strange logic, you will always have this value in the `request` in the `index` method. If you want to know this variable inside all class methods - declare the variable in `__construct`. maybe you meant something more